# Basic syntax array declaration

Tags: c++

If I am using an int as the array size when declaring a new array lint complains. What is the correct way to resolve this:

I could statically cast int to unsigned but that looks a bit odd...

What is the best way to resolve this without changing the use of an array and the need for integer as size?

```
MapItemPtr* pMapItems = new MapItemPtr[ (unsigned int)iRecordCount ];
```

Could do:

```
MapItemPtr* pMapItems = new MapItemPtr[static_cast<unsigned int>( iRecordCount )];
```

Is this the correct way to resolve the lint error: 
Line 3811 Error 737: Loss of sign in promotion from int to unsigned int

or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You submit 7 questions, post no votes and accept no answers.

Comment: You are not contributing back to this community at present.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. When somebody has answered I have always just replied with a thank you message. I didn't realise that I could do these things. I will go back to my posts and rectify.

Comment: Yep, you should always upvote the ones you like, and accept the one that best solves your problem (if any of them do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `iRecordCount` is clearly intended to hold a nonnegative integer, why not just declare it as `unsigned int` in the first place?

Comment: Indeed, it should be a `size_t`.

Comment: But if `iRecordCount` is a constant integral expression (as it must be, if it is used as the dimension of an array), lint is surely off base complaining about it here.

Comment: Yes I agree. Even when the variable is const int of value greater than 0 it still complains which I think is wrong. Variable cannot be changed as it is const. Perhaps lint doesn't evaluate the code properly in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The error is not the constness of the variable, as the lint said:

```
 : Line 3811 Error 737: Loss of sign in promotion from int to unsigned int.
```

You have a few options:

1 - `static_cast<>` `int` to `unsigned int`,
2 - `(unsigned int*)` c-style cast, but that should be avoided in c++ code.
3 - create a temporary `unsigned int` variable that will create the vector for you.

since you are just creating an array, the type of the variable could be `size_t`, declared in `cstddef`.

Comment: Thanks for all of your advice guys. I have simply changed the int to an unsigned int as this seems the most practical? I have marked ticked an answer. So how do I upvote now then? As you may be able to tell as a programmer I have pretty shocking IT skills haha.